# How auto refresh component when data updated from api, without page refresh

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I’m trying to make component like a **LIKE** count,

so,
i have a object is name **(LIST)** which i get from api, in my **LIST** object have property total_like which default value is 0, when i click to like button i make post request to api and in api my total_like value rising to 1 and 2 and etc.
in my view i’m displaying the like count with **{{item.total_like}}** everything work well to this point.

problem is **item.total_like** value updating only when i refresh the page, but i want to show new value of this property without refreshing page.

how can i figure out with it ?

regards

Comment: probably looking for ajax.

Comment: likely a reactivity issue, please provide a code sample for us to help you find what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the event modifiers to prevent page reloading, examples are...

```
<button type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="addLike" >

<button type="submit" v-on:submit.prevent="addLike">
```

or if you want to use the shorthand

```
<button type="submit" @click.prevent="addLike" >

<button type="submit" @submit.prevent="addLike">
```

Hope this helps.